# Deploying my classic desktop application as a portable exe, without any setup or installation file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, desktop-application, portability

I have finalized a classic desktop app that mostly does some windows administrative stuff through different protocols (vbscript, CMD, ...) and it is working perfectly.
What I need is to put the app on a USB drive and perform the process on several computers. How can I get the Visual Studio to create a single exe file that runs from a USB drive and doesn't need to be installed and setup on each and every computer?

Comment: Have you tried looking in your `yourProjectDirectory\bin\Debug` directory? (Or `yourProjectDirectory\bin\Release` depending on your configuration)

Comment: yes, but i don't know what should i do or what should i change in my project preferences settings, that is why i am asking experts...

Comment: Just copy the `.exe` to your USB drive and run it on another computer?

Comment: Unless you've changed something in your project or unless you're using another project type; the resulting `.exe` in the `Debug` or `Release` folder should be completely portable (plus/minus any references/external resources it needs, but this depends on how you've built your application).

Comment: thanks, i thought so, but it gives me a very long error in middle of the process... i guess it is related to the target .Netframwork version i have used, i am trying to find that out.

Comment: What version are you targeting, and what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

as Visual Vincent said, it is the .exe file in the either debug or release directory of the project.
the problem was the .Netframwork version. and i fixed it. So the question was incorrect.